# Is there an official OpenAI nuget package to be able to use its API?

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I want to use the openAI API in a console app project in Visual Studio but I don't know if they have released an official nuget package.

[image]

I understand that this is not true?

If they haven't released it, what is the best way to start testing their API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is now an official nuget package (by Microsoft) that also supports Azure OpenAI.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.AI.OpenAI/

However it is still in preview at the time of this post.

Comment: It is not an official Nuget package by OpenAI. 
It is Microsoft's official package that also supports OpenAI

Comment: @Tolga true, I assumed a microsoft package because of the tags of the question. Still, some people probably prefer a Microsoft package over a community SDK.

Answer (score 1):

right now, we have two libraries in community libraries but nothing that allows the swap among Azure and OpenAi, but I found a library that does it. Till now it's always been updated.
I'm using this [library](https://github.com/KeyserDSoze/Rystem.OpenAi) Rystem.OpenAi from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rystem.OpenAi).
It's very cool, I like the fluent concept and how I can swap among OpenAi or Azure endpoints for free.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34181688)

Answer (score 0):

https://platform.openai.com/docs/libraries/community-libraries

Dotnet SDK for OpenAI Chat GPT, GPT-3 and DALL·E
Unofficial.
GPT-3 doesn't have any official .Net SDK.

https://github.com/betalgo/openai